# Replace single quotes with double quotes inside string

Tags: javascript, regex, object

My code replaces all object key with double quotes but the value with single quotes is not getting replaced

```
var str = "db.projects.insert({'projectid':'1001','projteamname':'DBTeam','amount':100})"
var objKeysRegex = /({|,)(?:\s*)(?:')?([A-Za-z_$\.][A-Za-z0-9_ \-\.$]*)(?:')?(?:\s*):/g;// look for object names
str = str.replace(objKeysRegex, "$1\"$2\":");// all object names should be double quoted
console.log(str)
```

I am not able to get the below result

```
Expected ouput
db.projects.insert({"projectid":"1001","projteamname":"DBTeam","amount":100})
```

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `str.replace(/'/g, '"');`?

Comment: Just `JSON.stringify({'projectid':'1001','projteamname':'DBTeam','amount':100})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a pattern such as:

```
([{:,])'(\w+)'/g;
```

And replace with:

```
$1\"$2\"
```

```js
var str = "db.projects.insert({'projectid':'1001','projteamname':'DBTeam','amount':100})"
var objKeysRegex = /([{:,])'(\w+)'/g; 
str = str.replace(objKeysRegex, '$1\"$2\"');
alert(str)
```

Result:

> db.projects.insert({"projectid":"1001","projteamname":"DBTeam","amount":100})

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're overcomplicating things here, if all you want to do is to replace all those quotes, this will suffice:

```js
var str = "db.projects.insert({'projectid':'1001','projteamname':'DBTeam','amount':100})";
alert(str.replace(/'/g, '"'));
```

Comment: @Cerbus replace will fail in case if no quotes is provided var str = "db.projects.insert({projectid:'1001',projteamname:'DBTeam',amount:100})"

Comment: True, but where are you getting that string from then? Also, you're aware that those quotes are optional in JavaScript, for the keys, right?